# How make hand touch without going through?

Tags: collision

I want to make two hand touch each other without than going through one another.

Comment: Hi, if you mean running a physics simulation, look into collision properties. Otherwise, please detail more about your project.

Comment: you can not, you can fake it with animation, and you can add some mesh deformations if you want to add a bit of realism

Comment: I want to create an animation of two hands holding each other to look as realistic as possible.